# How to do the key and value output from the dictionary in the label?

Tags: c#, winforms

There are 10 labels and a dictionary which consists of the key-name of the player, a label-record (in seconds).

The first 5 labels are made under the names (ie, as a table of records), and the remaining 5 labels under the results.

I need to derive this data from the dictionary and sort it by label, the less seconds, the higher the person in the ranking.

It is necessary to do something so that the player, who in the first place displays his name and result.

10 labels in the table are arranged like this (I am writing the label numbers):

```
label18 label28

label19 label29

label20 label30

label21 label31

label22 label32
```

There is also a code for how to make a dictionary (it may be useful):

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> AllNames()
    {
        return File
          .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\картинки\results.txt")
          .Where(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
          .Select(item => item.Split(' '))
          .ToDictionary(items => items[0],
                        items => int.Parse(items[1]));
    }
```

This should all happen by clicking on the button: "Show rating", which is on this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that you want put names into `label18..labe22` and values into `label28..label32` a simple *Linq* should do

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 private void updateRatingLabels() {
   var tops = AllNames()
     .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)                      // less seconds - better rank
     .ThenBy(pair => pair.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal) // On tie, use names
     .Take(5)                                          // Top 5 or less  
     .ToArray();

   // Clear all the labels
   for (int i = 18; i <= 22; ++i)
     Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

   for (int i = 28; i <= 32; ++i)
     Controls.Find($"label{i}", true).First().Text = "";

   // Put best results
   for (int i = 0; i < tops.Length; ++i) {
     Controls.Find($"label{i + 18}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Key;
     Controls.Find($"label{i + 28}", true).First().Text = tops[i].Value.ToString();
   }
 }
```

Then

```
  private void buttonShow_Rating_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    updateRatingLabels();  
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194242/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-bychenko-how-to-do-the-key-and-value-output-from).